# Selected Values are not storing in AddObject in didSelectRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Selected objects are not saving in addObject in didSelectRowAtIndex and I need to pass that array in another view controller.

```
@implementation nextViewController
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray * arrayfortable;
    NSMutableArray * selectedIndexpath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableArray *selectedIndexpath = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    selectedIndexpath = [selectedIndexpath arrayByAddingObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@"selected",selectedIndexpath);

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        __selectedPath = indexPath;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        __selectedPath = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedIndexpath = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

is creating a new local variable named `selectedIndexpath` that is hiding the `selectedIndexpath` instance variable.

You need to remove that line. But you do need to initialize the instance variable.

I would add the following line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
selectedIndexpath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

One other needed change is to replace the line:

```
selectedIndexpath = [selectedIndexpath arrayByAddingObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

with:

```
[selectedIndexpath addObject:@(tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row)];
```

Note that you need to wrap the index path row as an `NSNumber`.